# SQL Server WHERE based on CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wanna search for all rows where TAX = 'asd' if PARAM equals 1, else all rows where TAX <> 'asd' (every row that isn't 'asd').

Something like this:

```
WHERE
  TAX (
     CASE
        WHEN PARAM = '1'
           THEN = 'asd'
        ELSE <> 'asd'
     END)
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `case` expressions in `where` clauses. Use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `where` clause with Boolean logic :

```
WHERE (PARAM = 1 AND TAX = 'asd') OR
      (PARAM <> 1 AND TAX <> 'asd');
```

If, the `PARAM` has NUMERIC type, then you don't need to include `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a `CASE` statement just use brackets and `OR`.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE (TAX = 'asd' AND PARAM = '1') OR (TAX != 'asd')
```

Comment: Beware: it will select `(TAX, PARAM) = ('fds', '1')`

Comment: @SalmanA They didn't specify they wouldn't want != asd & =1

Comment: The `CASE` statement (when fixed) will produce different result from what you've posted. OP is clear that if param is 1 they want asd otherwise anything other than asd.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROm table
WHERE (TAX = 'asd' AND PARAM IN (1))
OR (TAX <> 'asd' AND PARAM NOT IN (1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with OR, AND and some brackets:

```
WHERE (PARAM = 1 AND TAX = 'asd')
OR (TAX <> 'asd')
```

Be sure to consider cases where TAX may be NULL, unless that is explicitly prohibited by your database design.